# scipy.optimize.minimize giving partially incorrect result

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to find regression model parameters using Maximum Likelihood Estimation. I have assumed that the error term follows a normal distribution. My code goes like this..

```
def lik(parameter):
m=parameter[0]
b=parameter[1]
sigma=parameter[2]
for i in np.arange(0,len(x)):
    y_exp=m * x + b
    L=(len(x)/2)*np.log(2*np.pi)+len(x)/2*np.log(sigma**2)+(1/(2*sigma**2))+sum((y-y_exp)**2)
return L

lik_model=minimize(lik,np.array([5,5,5]),method='Nelder-Mead')
print(lik_model)
```

I am supplying x and y from a pandas Dataframe. x contains the following data: 1,3,2,1,3.y contains the following data: 14,24,18,17,27.

I am getting the following output..

```
final_simplex: (array([[ 4.99995861, 10.00010678, -0.44724658],
   [ 4.9999851 , 10.00003754, -0.44716575],
   [ 4.9999644 , 10.0001883 , -0.4471848 ],
   [ 4.99988178, 10.00019657, -0.4471765 ]]), array([17.07109792, 17.07109794, 17.07109798, 17.07109798]))
       fun: 17.071097921871136
   message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
      nfev: 156
       nit: 85
    status: 0
   success: True
         x: array([ 4.99995861, 10.00010678, -0.44724658])
```

In x:array([4.9999,10.000106,-0.4472]), the first and the second value is correct which I verified by OLS. However, the last value which gives the standard deviation of the error term is incorrect. The correct standard deviation of error was calculated as follows:

```
tbl=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Hrithik-PC/.spyder-py3/anova1.xlsx')
import statsmodels.api as sm
x=tbl['TV Ads']
y=tbl['Car Sold']
x2=sm.add_constant(x)
model=sm.OLS(y,x2)
fit=model.fit()
#print(fit.summary())
e=fit.resid
stde=np.std(e)
```

'stde' gives the correct standard deviation of the error term.

```
stde
Out[41]: 1.6733200530681507
```

So why am I getting an incorrect value for standard deviation of error term when I use minimize function ? I tried the same code with a different dataset. I got the correct first and second value in x:([]) after minimizing but the third value was incorrect. Rather the third value was the same as that for the previous dataset i.e. '-0.4472'
Why is this happening ? Please help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe local minima?

Comment: Could u please elaborate... where does the concept of local minima come in when I am trying to fit data on a straight line?